# Doctrine2 YML: Enforcing referential integrity

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using Doctrine2 with Symfony2. My backend Db is MySQL.

This is a snippet of the YML of an entity that has a many to one relationship:

```
manyToOne:
    region:
        targetEntity: Region
        inversedBy: districts
        joinColumn:
            name: region_id
            referencedColumnName: id 
            onDelete: RESTRICT
            onUpdate: CASCADE
```

When I view the generated schema, this is what it shows:

```
ALTER TABLE District ADD CONSTRAINT FK_C8B736D198260155 FOREIGN KEY (region_id) REFERENCES Region (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

How do I enforce the type of RI that I want (`Delete RESTRICT, Update CASCADE`), by expressing it in YML?

Comment: onUpdate was removed in doctrine. Why using an onUpdate cascade ?

Comment: Referential Integrity. If my PKs get updated, I want to cascade that through dependent tables.

Comment: Ok, however this feature was removed... and update object identity makes no sense for me in OO

Comment: @PerroinThibault: Are you familiar with database referential integrity?

Comment: Yes, I am. I don't know why Doctrine has removed this option. It is very useful, but this is database-side and Doctrine doesn't provide this feature